# Concatenate lines together if they are not emty in a file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, newline

I have a file where some sentence are spread over multiple lines.
For example:

```
1:1 This is a simple sentence
[NEWLINE]
1:2 This line is spread over 
multiple lines and it goes on
and on.
[NEWLINE]
1:3 This is a line spread over
two lines
[NEWLINE]
```

So I want it to look like this

```
1:1 This is a simple sentence
[NEWLINE]
1:2 This line is spread over multiple lines and it goes on and on.
[NEWLINE]
1:3 This is a line spread over two lines
```

Some lines a spread over 2 or 3 or 4 lines. If there follows al line which is not an new line it should be merged into one single line.
I would like to overwrite the given file of to make an new file.

I've tried it with a while loop but without succes.

```
input = open(file, "r")
zin = ""
lines = input.readlines()
#Makes array with the lines
for i in lines:
    while i != "\n"
        zin += i
.....
```

But this creates a infinite loop.

Comment: you can use regex and remove single /n or /r

Comment: How did you determine that a sentence is actually on multiple lines ? That doesn't compute with me... there must be an end of line character in the file, like \n or \r (or both)... unless you are using an editor which "wraps" depending on the width of the editor on screen... e.g. if you are using a tool like notepad.exe on windows, there is a function "Word Wrap" in the "Format" pull-down menu. If that is selected it will wrap sentences depending on Window-width. Please examine your file more carefully to ensure that the "wrapped sentences" are not due to the tool you use to view. HTH, Edwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be nesting `for` and `while` loops in your use case. What happens in your code is that a line is assigned to the variable `i` by the `for` loop, but it isn't being modified by the nested `while` loop, so if the `while` clause is `True`, then it will remain that way and without a breaking condition, you end up with an infinite loop.

A solution might look like this:

```
single_lines = []
current = []

for i in lines:
    i = i.strip()
    if i:
        current.append(i)
    else:
        if not current:
            continue  # treat multiple blank lines as one
        single_lines.append(' '.join(current))
        current = []
else:
    if current:
        # collect the last line if the file doesn't end with a blank line
        single_lines.append(' '.join(current))
```

Good ways of overwriting the input file would be to either collect all output in memory, close the file after reading it out and reopen it for writing, or to write to another file while reading the input and renaming the second one to overwrite the first after closing both.

Comment: Oke, but how would you suggest to make an new file/ overwrite the other file. So I get the wanted "Syntax"

Comment: The current.append(i) does give an error " AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a bug in my code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Because you should be using `+` instead of `*`. Your expression says, delete all ":" that are preceded by *zero or* more digits and followed by *zero or* more digits. This is true of any ":" in the line.

Comment: Oke, yes I fixed it 
Thanks